# VSCODE connot find default build task

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to build a C++ application with VSCode.

- installed VSCODE
- installed C++ extension
- installed compiler, adding to path
- created demo source file
- created build task, marked as default

When I try to run, I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that I can build by using

```
Terminal | Run Build Task
```